# Why does colon notation work in place of a dot when executing a function?

Tags: javascript

I know you can use the `:` when

- [**initializing objects**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_Object_Initializers)
- [**using a ternary operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/Conditional_Operator)
- [**using labels**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label)

Opening my console in a Chrome browser I can execute:

```
window.open('http://google.ie')
```

That works fine. Then I type the same but using a colon instead:

```
window:open('http://google.ie')
```

Why does using a `:` still work and execute the `open` function?

Comment: Because [`open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open) is a global and the `:` makes `window` into a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label).

Comment: @JonathanLonowski - Sounds like an answer. It would be very clear with a few newlines after the colon how it works.

Comment: Additional experimentation to show that the `:` is not in fact replacing `.`-notation: `var foo={}; foo.bar=function(){}; foo:bar; //Gives ref error for bar` (i.e. don't use the global object to test it)

Comment: @ajp15243: I was just doing the same as I thought I imagined things and it off course didn't work. `window` being part of the global namespace completely threw me. Didn't see the forest for the trees.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `:` makes `window` into a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) rather than a variable:

```
window:
    open('...');

continue window;
```

And, since `window` is the global object in browsers, [`open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open) is a global function and can be directly referenced with or without it.

```
// both work
window.open('...');
open('...');
```

But, it's not a complete replacement for all objects and their properties:

```
var o = { foo: 'bar' };

o:foo // ReferenceError: foo is not defined
```

Comment: Yes, really weird syntax. Shame that javascript has `goto` sickness too :p

Comment: @JonathanLonowski: I see. I read about labels on the MDN but drew a complete blank to why this worked executing a function and didn't associate it with labels at all. Global namespace didn't even enter my mind at the time. I'm doing JavaScript for a few years now and still get moments where I'm drawing a complete blank like this. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: I've been writing JavaScript since the turn of the millennium and I had no idea about this syntax. Mind blown. I mean, obviously I still won't be using it... ;)